# How to retrieve a Doctrine record with all relational records?

Tags: doctrine, orm, foreign-key-relationship, record

I was wondering if there is a way to get a record with all relational data, something like a 'Deep-Fetch'

So if a model Child were related to another model Parent,
can we fetch Child & then access Child->Parent->name thru a single query?

Doctrine today fires a query whenever a relationship is accessed. Is this too costly? does it need to be optimizeD?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine automatically hydrates related objects when you select fields from that relations:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('a.*, c.*)
  ->from('Article a')
  ->innerJoin('Category c');
```

In this example both Article and Category objects are being hydrated (no additional queries are made).

Comment: thanks Kuba. this means that I will have to write my custom queries, and there is no overload of the fetch() magic method to do this!

Comment: You mean find* methods? Using them is anyway not advised (performance wise).